# Mysql_fetch_array print within a string. Possible?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, function

I'm kinda confused right now with this function I'm trying to edit. I would like to add the mysql_fetch_array to the feedback string. I'm pretty sure it's possible but can somebody point out the problem for me? The piece of code I'm trying to execute is in comments. And where's `PRINTHERE`, that where I want the `mysql_fetch_array` to spit out the results. Thx a lot!

```
foreach($_FILES as $k => $v){ 

    $img_type = "";

    ### $htmo .= "$k => $v<hr />";  ### print_r($_FILES);

    if( !$_FILES[$k]['error'] && preg_match("#^image/#i", $_FILES[$k]['type']) && $_FILES[$k]['size'] < $max_image_size ){

        $img_type = ($_FILES[$k]['type'] == "image/jpeg") ? ".jpg" : $img_type ;
        $img_type = ($_FILES[$k]['type'] == "image/gif") ? ".gif" : $img_type ;
        $img_type = ($_FILES[$k]['type'] == "image/png") ? ".png" : $img_type ;

        $img_rname = $_FILES[$k]['name'];
        $img_path = $upload_dir.$img_rname;

        copy( $_FILES[$k]['tmp_name'], $img_path ); 
        if($enable_thumbnails) make_thumbnails($upload_dir, $img_rname);
        /*
        mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("");        
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery_main ORDER BY datetime DESC");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
            $name=$row['name'];
            echo "<option value='$name'>$name</option>";
          }
         */ 
        $feedback .="<style>.stap1{display:none;}.stap2{display:block;}</style>
        <input name='src' style='width:400px;' type='hidden' value=\"$img_rname\"><br />
        <input name='thumbsrc' style='width:400px;' type='hidden' value=\"thumb_$img_rname\"><br />
        <select name='galleryname' id='galleryname'>PRINTHERE";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you the Andrew Ng of Stanford machine learning fame?

Comment: No, Im not. Just another guy with same name. hehehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of echoing, store the results into a variable, like you did with `$feedback`.

```
$options = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $name=$row['name'];
    $options .= "<option value='$name'>$name</option>";
}
```

Then, append to `$feedback`

```
$feedback .= "<style>.stap1{display:none;}.stap2{display:block;}</style>
        <input name='src' style='width:400px;' type='hidden' value=\"http://www.djpassa.com/gallery/$img_rname\"><br />
        <input name='thumbsrc' style='width:400px;' type='hidden' value=\"http://www.djpassa.com/gallery/thumb_$img_rname\"><br />
        <select name='galleryname' id='galleryname'>" . $options;
```

Also, you need to select a database.

```
mysql_select_db("database_name");
```

Comment: Hmm somehow it's still not working i've added the whole php file to this address: http://codepad.org/Y505gazf

Comment: Assuming your query is correct and retrieves at least 1 result, you need to select a database.

Comment: I've removed the info for security reasons. Even with the correct login info it wont parse the list out. Any more clues???

Comment: Can you confirm any content is concatenated to `$feedback`? If there is none, then there may be an issue with your SQL credentials or query. Also, add `</select>` to close off the select tag, but this shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: hi i've updated the code. This is what I have now: http://codepad.org/GpQwqJw4 it does spit out $lol which is lol in plain text. But not the $options

Comment: Then the problem here is with your SQL connection or query, however you would've received an error if it didn't connect. Append `or die(mysql_error())` to both `mysql_select_db` and your query, `mysql_query`, and see if this outputs an error.

Comment: Then, can you confirm there are rows to be retrieved as a result of your query?

Comment: If i change "$options ."<option value='$name'>$name</option>";" to $options ="<option value='$name'>$name</option>"; it will generate one select option. so in other word the query and connections are not the problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7898/discussion-between-josh-and-andrew-ng)

Comment: In case you don't join the chat, you need to change `$options . "<option>...."` to `$options .= "<options>...."` Notice the dot equals sign?